# Delete the last block from tezos-node storage?

Tags: node, storage, tezos-admin-client

How can I delete the head block stored in `tezos-node` storage?

I did something dumb - I modified the Octez code and then ran the modified `tezos-node` while pointing at the directory I use for my archive node.
The modified `tezos-node` updated the head but it saved it with bad metadata, which means the hash-chain is broken and so the chain can't grow.

Is it possible to just delete the last block in the chain, as stored on disk? I looked at the commands for `tezos-admin-client` but didn't find anything.

Thanks!

Comment: best to just re-import a snapshot; that way you know for sure it's consistent

Comment: You can't use snapshots for archive nodes, and it took me 3 weeks to sync this archive node 

Comment: Yea, archive nodes suck to create. Best to make one and then back it up somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to do such a thing. However, if the block is "just an alternative head", new blocks with better fitness should be considered and the node should switch to another branch. It depends on how it is broken.